# Matching database columns in the filtering in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to match database columns in the query. How is this possible?
For example

select * from docs where mlal_id_no=8 AND  column1= column2

`qs = docs.objects.filter(mlal_id_no=8,column1=column2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to another column with an [**`F`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F). So you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import F

qs = docs.objects.filter(mlal_id_no=8, column1=F('column2'))
```

`F`-objects are often used in expressions, for example when you add, multiply, subtract, aggregate, etc. columns.